# How can I say "Not only he doesn't" with "pas seulement"?

Tags: traduction, négation, constructions, coordination

- Tony n’est **pas seulement** un excellent professeur, c’est **aussi** un scientifique de grand talent.

When I see the "pas seulement ~~~ aussi", it is almost always about the affirmative statement: "Tony is A, and B". But how can I turn this phrase into a negative statement, such as,

- Tony **not only doesn't** like playing with children in his neibourhood, but he **also doesn't** take a good care of his own children **as well**.

I can't imagine using "pas seulement pas" for "not only not".

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it that way:

> Non seulement Tony n'aime pas jouer avec les enfants de son quartier, mais il ne s'occupe pas bien de ses propres enfants non plus.

Comment: You beat me by 6 seconds... ;-)

Comment: I thought YOU beat me the moment I hit "Enter"

Answer (score 1):

I rather would suggest :

> **Non seulement** Tony **n**'aime **pas** jouer avec les enfants du voisinage, mais il **ne** prend **pas non plus** soin de ses enfants.

Comment: 2 min late I guess...

Comment: At least there is some sort of consensus...

Answer (score 0):

I will go with:

> ***Non seulement*** il n'aime pas..., mais il ne prend pas **non plus** soin de....

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the *"non seulement"* suggested by several answers.

However, note that *"Tony **n**'est **pas** seulement*" is already negative (*"ne [...] pas"*). It's literally "is not only"